# How to get the size of a temp stream in PHP?

Tags: php, io

It seems like this ought to be really obvious, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Assuming I create a stream using `php://temp`, how do I get the length of the data written?

```php
$stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
// ... do some processing here using fwrite, stream_copy_to_stream, stream_filter_append, etc ...
$num_bytes_in_stream = // What goes here?
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way without reading it. I tried using `fstat($stream)` but it returns size=0.

Comment: @Barmar `fstat` seemed to return a valid value for me in a brief test. I'll see if that remains true in the complete code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php://temp uses a temporary file. The file is empty as long as nothing has been written. fopen expects at least 2 parameters. Mode "w+" can also be used in this case.

```
$stream = fopen('php://temp','r+');
var_dump(fstat($stream)['size']);  //int(0)

$r = fputs($stream,'1234');
var_dump(fstat($stream)['size']);  //int(4)

rewind($stream);
$str = fgets($stream,'1234');
var_dump($str, fstat($stream)['size']);  //string(4) "1234" int(4)
```

Try self on https://3v4l.org/Hsodg

Comment: Yeah, I know fopen requires 2 params, I accidentally left it off when I wrote the question I guess. The `fstat` function appears to be exactly what i needed though, thanks!

Comment: `rw` is not a valid mode. It should be `r+` or `w+` for read and write.

Comment: When I tried to test this yesterday I used `r` instead of `r+`. That's why I always got `0`.

Comment: I guess `rw` must be an undocumented mode, I'll upvote if you correct it to a documented mode.

Comment: sorry and thank you. 
    "r+" is the correct mode to indicate the behavior.

Comment: @Barmar The 'rw' mode just happened to work here in conjunction with 'php://temp'. Real files fail when writing with "rw" mode.